# jqGrid the correct way to expand column width

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xhtml, jqgrid-asp.net

I am attempting to widen my columns here with the colModel property of jqGrid.  when I do this, my table data disappears.  Does any body know why this would happen.  Before and after pictures will be below.  As well as the jquery code that I use.

[image]

Here is an example of it working.

[image]

Here is an example after I have attempted to widen the columns

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    ShowMessage();
    tableToGrid("#table1", {
        height: '200',
        shrinkToFit: false,
        autowidth: true,
        colNames: ['Edit',
                   'MRN',
                   'Hospital Fin',
                   'First Name',
                   'Last Name',
                   'Date of birth',
                   'Completed Pathway',
                   'Completed Pathway Reason',
                   'PCP Appointment',
                   'Specialist Appointment',
                   'Admit Date',
                   'Discharge Date',
                   'Discharge Disposition',
                   'Discharge To',
                   'Discharge Advocate Call',
                   'Home Healthcare',
                   'Safe Landing Accepted',
                   'PCP Name',
                   'PCP Phone',
                   'PCP Appointment Location',
                   'Specialist Name',
                   'Specialist Phone',
                   'Specialist Appointment Location',
                   'Comments',
                   'Patient Room',
                   'Phone',
                   'Payor',
                   'MRN Type'
                   ],
        colModel: [{ name: 'Edit', width: 55 },
                   { name: 'MRN',  width: 55 },
                   { name: 'HospitalFin', width: 85 },
                   { name: 'FirstName',  width: 85 },
                   { name: 'LastName',  width: 85 },
                   { name: 'Dateofbirth',  width: 85 },
                   { name: 'CompletedPathway',  width: 145 },
                   { name: 'CompletedPathwayReason',  width: 165 },
                   { name: 'PCPAppointment',  width: 145 },
                   { name: 'SpecialistAppointment', width: 165 },
                   { name: 'AdmitDate', width: 55 },
                   { name: 'DischargeDate', width: 80 },
                   { name: 'DischargeDisposition', width: 180 },
                   { name: 'DischargeTo', width: 55 },
                   { name: 'DischargeAdvocateCall', width: 165 },
                   { name: 'HomeHealthCareAccepted', width: 165 },
                   { name: 'SafeLandingAccepted', width: 165 },
                   { name: 'PCPName', width: 55 },
                   { name: 'PCPPhone', width: 55 },
                   { name: 'PCPAppointmentLocation', width: 165 },
                   { name: 'SpecialistName', width: 185 },
                   { name: 'SpecialistPhone', width: 185 },
                   { name: 'SpecialistAppointmentLocation', width: 185 },
                   { name: 'Comments', width: 55 },
                   { name: 'PatientRoom', width: 85 },
                   { name: 'Phone', width: 85 },
                   { name: 'Payor', width: 85 },
                   { name: 'MRNType', width: 85 }
                   ]
    });
    $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        $("#table1").fluidGrid({ example: "#tempplateInfo", offset: -10 });
        $("#table1 tbody").sortable("destroy");
    });
    (function ($) {
        jQuery.jgrid.fluid = {
            fluidGrid: function (options) {
                var grid = $(this);
                var settings = $.extend({
                    example: grid.closest('.ui-jqgrid').parent(), offset: 0
                },
                options || {});
                var width = $(settings.example).innerWidth() + settings.offset; grid.setGridWidth(width);
            }
        }
    })
    (jQuery);
    jQuery.fn.extend({ fluidGrid: jQuery.jgrid.fluid.fluidGrid });

    var $grid = $('#table1'),
        hdiv = $grid[0].grid.hDiv,
        $columnHeaders = $("thead tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th", hdiv)
    $columnHeaders.unbind('mouseenter');
    $columnHeaders.unbind('mouseleave');
```

Comment out the columnModel section to get an idea of what I had when it was working.  Should the colModel name property be equal to the th for instance?  What is the word good fellows.  I am getting inconsitent results.

Comment: Have you tried adding [other options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) to the columnModel section? Maybe there is one you are missing. And try removing the "autowidth" option.

Comment: autowidth is needed to make my table the width of the container.

Comment: I see that now. Sorry, I've not use the jqGrid in a while. Anyway, try applying other options to your colModel, like "align" or "resizable" before setting the width. Have you tried opening your page in Firefox or Crome? Maybe you could use Firebug to see if the data in the grid is there, maybe it is just not being displayed.

Comment: the table is definitly there. I use TableToGrid().  The thing is, when I use colModel, the Data disappears.  That is some real wild stuff.  Do you know a responsive web forum that I can go to that has user who use jqgrid where I can get some help?  Any help would be appreciated.  Is there a way you can set a global default width?  That might have to do for now.  Can I do it with cmTemplate?

Comment: Try on the [jqGrid forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/) and the [jqGrid Wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php). I still believe that you are missing something in colModel. To set your width try with the "rownumWidth", "width" and "shrinkToFit" [options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options&s[]=column&s[]=width). "cmTemplate" could do it too. Good luck.

Comment: Apparently, with colModel when naming the columns, you need to put _ in the places where there are spaces in the <td></td>.  But that is not always the case.  This thing is a piece of trash.